# parsing data from website json table with beautiful soup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm sure this will be a quick fix for someone with reasonable knowledge of web-scraping with beautifulsoup. I'm trying to grab the data from a table but for some reason its not giving me the expected output. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

def main():

    # BASE AND EXTENTIONS FOR EACH CURRENCY COLUMNWISE
    base_cols_url='https://uk.reuters.com/assets/'
    forex_cols={}
    forex_cols['GBP']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=GBP'
    forex_cols['EUR']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=EUR'
    forex_cols['USD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=USD'
    forex_cols['JPY']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=JPY'
    forex_cols['CHF']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CHF'
    forex_cols['AUD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=AUD'
    forex_cols['CAD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CAD'
    forex_cols['CNY']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CNY'
    forex_cols['HKD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=HKD'

    # loop through the pages
    for sym in forex_cols:
        print(sym)
        print(base_cols_url+forex_cols[sym])
        get_data_from_page(sym,base_cols_url+forex_cols[sym])


def get_data_from_page(SYMBOL,PAGE):

    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    # PARSE THE HTML
    browser.get(PAGE)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    rows = soup.findAll('td')

    # PARSE ALL THE COLUMN DATA
    for r in rows:
        print(r)      # this prints nothing  

    print(soup)       # this prints the page but the markups are missing and replaced with  '&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt'
    return        

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

If I manually load the page in chrome I can see the 'td' and 'tr' markups that should be able to be parsed but for some reason nothing prints? However, if I just print the entire soup object it seems that the markups are missing which explains why print(r) returns nothing. However, I don't know how to parse out the parts I need? (the data displayed on the table in the base webpage: https://uk.reuters.com/business/currencies).

Would really like an explanation about whats going on here? It looks like  format called json but I've never never really used it and when I tried json.loads(soup) it says it can't load a soup object, so I try json.loads(soup.text()) but I get a ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Would be really grateful if anyone could help me parse the data? Many thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some failed attempts with json, I tried an incredibly crude basic string parsing method but it does the job, just in case anyone else wants to do anything similar.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

def main():

    # BASE AND EXTENTIONS FOR EACH CURRENCY COLUMNWISE
    base_cols_url='https://uk.reuters.com/assets/'
    forex_cols={}
    forex_cols['GBP']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=GBP'
    forex_cols['EUR']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=EUR'
    forex_cols['USD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=USD'
    forex_cols['JPY']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=JPY'
    forex_cols['CHF']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CHF'
    forex_cols['AUD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=AUD'
    forex_cols['CAD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CAD'
    forex_cols['CNY']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=CNY'
    forex_cols['HKD']='jsonCurrencyPairs?callback=drawCurrencyPairs&srcCurr=HKD'

    for sym in forex_cols:
        print(sym)
        print(base_cols_url+forex_cols[sym])
        get_data_from_page(sym,base_cols_url+forex_cols[sym])


def get_data_from_page(SYMBOL,PAGE):

    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    # PARSE THE HTML
    browser.get(PAGE)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    rows = str(soup).split('"row"')

    # PARSE ALL THE COLUMN DATA
    for r in rows:
        # PARSE OUT VALUE COL
        try:
            print(r.split('&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;')[1].split('&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class=')[0])
        except: IndexError
        pass
        # PARSE OUT CURRENCY PAIR
        try:
            print(r.split('sparkchart?symbols=')[1].split('=X&amp;')[0])
        except: IndexError
        pass

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```